# Compare variable is greater/less in Matlab

Tags: matlab

how to determine is a variable is greater or equal to a value in MATLAb , I tried :

```
if (myVar >= '123.1')
do mething here
else
do other thing
end
```

but it seems doing other thing each time !!

I see warning on '123.1' saying that is seldom , is there a function to compare ?

Comment: What is the value of `myVar`...

Comment: I cannot recreate your error. Your code (as it is) is correct, the only possible error is as @excaza suggested, with the value/type of your myVar; Maybe it is a vector/matrix instead of a single value?

Comment: emm... myVar is a char, sorry I forgot ''

Comment: As other commenters has asked: What is the value of `myVar`? If `myVar` is an array and one of its entry is zero, the condition will evaluate to false. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700071/why-does-this-matlab-if-statement-not-work

Comment: You probably do *not* want to evaluate `myVar >= '123.1'`... What is `myVar` supposed to be? A string? A number? Something else?

Comment: If `myVar` is a char, you need to convert it to a numeric data type

Comment: The output of `myVar >= '123.1'` is a boolean vector of length 5. Last I checked, `if` required a scalar boolean value to work properly. RHS should be `123.1`, or better yet `char(123)`. Surrounding 123.1 with `'` will make MATLAB treat it as a vector (think of it as `myVar == ['1','2','3','.','1']` ).

Comment: @Dev-iL *The output of `myVar >= '123.1'` is a zeros vector of length 5.* Not true in all cases. For instance, if  `myVar` has value `128`, then `myVar >= '123.1'` is an array of five logical `1`'s. *Last I checked, if required a scalar boolean value to work properly.* That depends on what you mean by "properly"; MATLAB allows for the condition of an `if` statement to be an array (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700071/why-does-this-matlab-if-statement-not-work)).

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks for the correction. In the first case I meant to say `boolean`, no idea why I went with zeros initially. As for the `if` input as an array - I'm assuming MATLAB implicitly calls `all(array)` so that the "final input to the `if`" is a single boolean value. This seems to agree with the explanation in your linked answer.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing characters logically performs an implicit type conversion prior to comparison (I'm assuming using [`double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html)).

So when you type `'123' >= '234'` you are actually performing:

```
[double('1') >= double('2'), ... % 49 >= 50
double('2') >= double('3'), ...  % 50 >= 51
double('3') >= double('4') ...   % 51 >= 52
 ];
```

This will error if your strings are different lengths. Convert your data for comparison with something like [`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) or [`str2num`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) prior to entering your logic statement.

For example:

```
strvar = '123.2';

if str2double(strvar) >= 123.1
    disp('True!')
else
    disp('False!')
end
```

With the appropriate [floating point approximation caveat](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)